# Is it possible to use the created like button on this website (https://likebtn.com/en/) in an app being developed in Smartface App Studio?

Tags: smartface.io

Is it possible to use the created like button on this website (https://likebtn.com/en/) in an app being developed in Smartface App Studio?

I've tried adding the like button onto a website and it was very successful.

Thankyou☺

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with image button.You can create a button like that using following codes:

```
var myImgBtn = new SMF.UI.ImageButton({
        left : '10%',
        top : '10%',
        width : '20%',
        height : '10%',
        defaultImage : 'likebutton.png',
        highlightedImage : 'buttonhighlighted.png',
        inactiveImage : 'buttoninactive.png',
        text : 'Like',
        onPressed : function(e){
                  ...
                  }
        });
        Pages.Page1.add(myImgBtn);
```